# How to convert a HTML+Javascript page used to access an SQL server to an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple HTML page, which I only use on my local machine in my intranet, to create dynamic SQL queries using Javascript and ActiveX to interact with my SQL Server database (yes, client-side Javascript can interact with SQL databases using IE and ActiveX objects). It was originally created as a quick, short-term solution (I know it's insecure and client side DB access is a bad-practice).

The situation has changed, and I need a permanent solution. I've decided than an ASP.NET MVC application would be the cleanest solution. I have no experience with it, so I've been reading up on it and using tutorials to start building my page. My question pertains to the Javascript dynamic SQL query logic in my original application, and how to best implement that in my .NET app. Is there a clean and secure way to create dynamic SQL queries in ASP.NET MVC (using C#/raw SQL code/ADO.NET)? Or is it best practice to use the Entity Framework, and start from scratch?

Comment: Personal opinion: start from scratch with EF and don't build up your technical debt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance does not matter or your DB is small, use EF from scratch.

Comment: My tables aren't going to have more than a few thousand rows. Is that small?

Answer (score 0):

If u already have queries written for the application to interact with DB and if u want better control of their execution choose a simple ORM like dapper. If you are comfortable writing SQL queries, consider using dapper.

If your application needs simple straightforward transactions with database, EF would work fine.